# powershell Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress from end of range

Tags: powershell, dhcp

We use reservations starting from the end of our DHCP scopes for printers.

Get-DHCPServerv4FreeIpAddress starts from the beginning. Is there anyway to make it start from the end to the beginning?

Comment: Why does that matter? Why are you trying to manage a managed address pool yourself (by trying to specify where to take an adress from)? There are no "sub"scopes.

Comment: I agree with Ansgar, you should ideally let DHCP manage itself, if you want specific addresses applied to specific devices you should consider using DHCP reservations instead.

Comment: Because of the network design?

Comment: Then I suggest you adjust your DHCP scopes to match your network design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how large the scope is (and how many addresses were already used) you could potentially do this (for example if the scope is 253 addresses):

```
Get-DHCPServerv4FreeIpAddress -numaddresses 253 | Select -Last 1
```

Comment: Seems to work :) Did get that the number of ip adress doesnt match. (WARNING: The requested number of free IP addresses could not be found.) Probably because there is no such number of free adresses left.

Comment: I stumbled upon this question when I got the same warning (The requested number of free IP addresses could not be found). In my case this happens for Scopes where all IP addresses are excluded from distribution in the Address Pool.